# Fonts with wide international support

Tags: web-fonts, font-recommendation

What fonts support the widest range of characters? (Like Helvetica Neue LT W1G)

Need to work on an a website present in 25+ countries, and I'm looking for something I can use as a webfont.

**Update:** To make things even worse, it needs to have subpixel hinting so that it doesn't look like crap on Windows.

Comment: Japanese, Chinese, Hebrew, Arabic, etc. are not required to be the same font. Cyrillic on the other hand would be nice.

Comment: You need to search for OpenType faces that support Cyrillic.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for commercial fonts, the [URW Global](http://www.urw.de/cgi-bin1/dalcgi/source/searchdb.htd?searchchar=global&sprache=english) fonts are hard to beat, as they have Western, Cyrillic, Greek, Arabic *and* CJK plus assorted *other* asian glyphs.

Answer (score 2):

[Noto Sans](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Noto+Sans) has also (prerelease) [support for many non-latin scripts](https://code.google.com/p/noto/)